# Sonata admin bundle add new manyToOne entity to current entity

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I have an entity that has a manyToOne with a subsequent entity. On the edit page of the parent i have a 2 column layout. On the right i would like to list the current linked entities in the collection and then have an "add new" button to either create a new entity and link it or link an existing one.

i am looking at using a collection, but i cant seem to format it to only show the name of the child.

[image]
I have a solution where i use the "help" to print the topics but cant generate the add new button. The screenshot above shows a little of what i mean. it's rendering the whole form.

Answer (score 1):

you may test to add a key `btn_add` to "New" to the third parameter ?

`->add('topics', 'sonata_type_collection', array('btn_add' => "New"))`

Or be sure to your route /topic/create is available for your child entity ?

Comment: that works, which is good, but what isnt ideal is that it shows the whole form, when ideally i just want to show topic.name

Comment: And how about remove the others fields from your form and populate the information you need in the `addTopic` function in your parent ?

Comment: i need that form with all the fields for another part of the admin. i think i'm probably barking up the wrong tree with this solution. i'm gonna step back and have another think about what i want to do. thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

You could also check whats the parent admin in your embedded admin and add only fields if its not the admin which should only contain the topic.name.

```
if ($this->getRoot()->getClass() != 'Your\Parent\Class\Containing\Topic\Name') {
 $formMapper->add(...); // all fields for 'full' view going here
}
```

Be aware of fields which are required. If you don't fill them, you'll get an error on save if you don't fill them otherwise.